# populating a category menu with sub-categories dynamically in djnago template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have two django models, the first is main category table and the other is a sub-category model linked to the main model, it means each category have multiple sub categories.

What is the best way to dynamically populate my template in a side menu using {% for *** %}{% endfor %} in  and

for exemple:

here is the models.py:

```
 class cate(models.Model):
    ref = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50) 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class subcate(models.Model):
    sect = models.ForeignKey(cate, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, db_index=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foreign Key can relate back to the same model. So that a sub category is just a category instance that has another category as a parent.To relate to the same model, you can use the string **self** instead of using the class name:

```
parent = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name="sub_categories")
```

Using this, if a category has a no parent, it is a top-level category and if it has a parent, then it is a sub-category.

Hope that solved your problem.